# Unable to call mysql stored procedure from remote app

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have an app that is connected to a remote mysql database.
This app use the following user userapp@[APP_SERVER_IP]
On database there is a Stored Procedure that is working fine but I am unable to call it from the app.
I think it is because security issues.

```
CREATE USER 'userapp'@'[APP_SERVER_IP]' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'userapp@'[APP_SERVER_IP]';
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION AppStoredProcedure TO 'userapp'@'[APP_SERVER_IP]';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Also I have the same user on the DEFINER of the stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'userapp'@'[APP_SERVER_IP]' PROCEDURE `AppStoredProcedure`(
        IN `_someid` INTEGER,
        IN `_somedate` DATE
    )
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN START TRANSACTION;
...
```

MySQL version is 5.6.49

Comment: What error are you getting? Why do you think it's a security issue?

Comment: Could be permissions, firewall, ports, or any number of things if you have the error that would help.

Comment: BTW, it's not necessary to use `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` That's only needed if you update the internal tables directly rather than using commands like `GRANT`.

Comment: I think is about permissions. I am not getting any arror, just the procedure is not being called. I will try to debug it.

Comment: If it were a permission problem you'd get an error, it wouldn't just ignore the call silently.